# Use custom authorities with Okta Spring Boot Starter

Tags: spring-security, okta

I am using version `1.4.0` of the [Okta Spring Boot Starter](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot) to validate incoming JWT tokens. By using the Starter, both authentication and authorization works out of the box (the default works so well you don't even need to define anything in your own security configuration).

But the default created roles are not to my liking, so I want to map the incoming scopes & roles to my own defined Spring authorities. When using the plain OAuth starter, one can define a `AuthoritiesExtractor` bean to do [just](https://medium.com/@bvulaj/mapping-your-users-and-roles-with-spring-boot-oauth2-a7ac3bbe8e7f) that:

```
@Bean
public AuthoritiesExtractor authoritiesExtractor() {
  return new YourOwnAuthoritiesExtractor();
}
```

Next to that, there is also the option to implement a custom [jwtAuthenticationConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234971/2049986) in your security configuration:

```
http
  ..
  .oauth2ResourceServer()
  .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(new JwtAuthenticationConverter() {

    @Override
    protected Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(final Jwt jwt) {
      // implementation
    }
  
  })
```

But all of these things seems not to work with the Okta Starter, because the extractors are never called when a JWT token is send to the server. Does someone know how to implement it for Okta?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
It's not possible with the standard Okta Starter at the moment.

**Explanation**
As Okta uses its own configurer to setup the oauth2ResourceServer, you cannot use a custom JwtAuthenticationConverter as it will be overridden by the one Okta [defines](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/blob/46f0032e99ca70066bfb737d143f2ff6d5a71ee7/oauth2/src/main/java/com/okta/spring/boot/oauth/OktaOAuth2Configurer.java#L98). Neither can you use the AuthoritiesExtractor, as the interface is not even packaged with the Okta Starter.

To overcome this issue, Okta introduced the concept of the `AuthoritiesProvider` interface. By defining a custom bean, you can *add* you own authorities to the ones already set by Okta :

```
@Bean
AuthoritiesProvider myCustomAuthoritiesProvider() {
  return (user, userRequest) -> lookupExtraAuthoritesByName(user.getAttributes().get("email"));
}
```

Sadly enough, the AuthoritiesProvider interface only supports authorization code flow and not resource servers. As long as [#160](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/issues/160) is not resolved, there will be no native suport for Opaque and JWT.