# Spring Security oauth2Login OAuth2UserService not executed after authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-admin

I have a Spring Boot Admin app secured by Keycloak, I defined a user having a realm role `ACTUATOR`.
The problem is that after authentication Spring Security does not have access to realm roles. I can see the granted authorities: `Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER, SCOPE_actuator_access, SCOPE_profile'`

Looking at the doc I found this section: [Delegation-based strategy with OAuth2UserService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-oauth2userservice) and this is my configuration:

This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/error","/instances", "/**/*.css", "/**/img/**", "/**/third-party/**", "/*.js" )
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasRole( "ACTUATOR" )
                .and()
                .oauth2Login( oauth2 -> oauth2.userInfoEndpoint(
                        userInfo -> userInfo.oidcUserService( this.oidcUserService() ) ) );
    }

    // I just copy-paste the doc's code to play with it...
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {

        final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();

        return ( userRequest ) -> {
            OidcUser oidcUser = delegate.loadUser( userRequest );

            //TODO find a way to extract realm roles 
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = userRequest.getAccessToken();

            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            oidcUser = new DefaultOidcUser( mappedAuthorities, oidcUser.getIdToken(), oidcUser.getUserInfo() );

            return oidcUser;
        };
    }
```

I hoped use the method `oidcUserService()` to extract Keycloak realm roles from the token but the method is not executed at all. I mean after successful authentication from Keycloak and redirected to the application, `oidcUserService()` method is not executed. It seems only executed at application startup, which is strange.

The question is how can I retrieve realm roles in this scenario?

**EDIT**

I added a sample project here: https://github.com/akuma8/sba-keycloak-spring-security

The security configurations are in `application.yml` and in `SecurityConfig` class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found why the `oidcUserService()` method was not invoked after authentication. The reason is the type of the token, I have dumbly copied the code from Spring Security documentation without making attention about that information.

In the documentation it's about `OidcUserRequest` whereas in my case it's `OAuth2UserRequest`, so it's a clash between `OAUTH2` vs `OIDC`. Changing the method to:

```
private OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> oauth2UserService() {
   // code extracting authorities from JWT here

}
```

Solved my issue. I am now able to get Keycloak realm roles from the access token.

Comment: You have no idea how much this answer helped me. The Spring docs sidetracked me for almost a week on a trivial problem. Aaaargh, but now it works as intended, so, thank you x 1_000!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell why this oidcUserService isn't invoked. You can use [JwtAuthenticationConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.10.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtAuthenticationConverter.html) instead and map you JWT to whatever role you need.

It's a bit tricky so here are two examples:

- https://dev.to/toojannarong/spring-security-with-jwt-the-easiest-way-2i43 (up-to-date but a bit too broad, look at the "custom claim" part)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234971/1722236 (outdated)

Note I don't know if you should check the JWT signature yourself before parsing it or if Spring OAuth will do it. That'd be worth checking.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I would like to avoid using the Keycloak Adapter. I use Spring security 5 which provides fully Oauth2 support. The only problem is that we have to customize many things.

Comment: @akuma8 could you put a sample project on Github ? Without a view on all the customization you're talking about it's hard to figure why it doesn't work...

Comment: Parsing JWT is suitable in the case of a resource server, in my case it is not the case. I have some projects where I use that approach because a bearer token is present in the `Authorization` header. Also, as you can see the `jwt()` method followes the `oauth2ResourceServer()` element and in my case I use `oauth2Login()`.

Comment: Sorry then, I still don't get it. Your authorization server is Keycloak. I understood the spring boot admin app contained resources you want to protect. If your app is just an Oauth2 provider then what does it provide access to ? Also, what is the DefaultOidcUser constructor you use doing if not parsing the JWT claims and (among other things) map them to roles ? How do you plan to get the correct role without parsing the JWT (or having the spring oauth lib do it for you) ?

Comment: SBA does not provide any resources, it's an ui application protected by Keycloak but it could be protected by any IAM provider. I know that I have to parse the JWT but with Spring Security 5, using the `oauth2ResourceServer()` is not the best way to go. Using `oauth2ResourceServer()` will not redirect the user to the authorization server for authentication. `oauth2ResourceServer()` is a passive way, the resource server simply verifies that the provided token is correct or not but not redirect for authorization whereas `oauthLogin()` does. I think I found a solution, I'll let you know. Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining. In the end I'm the one needing explanations here, sorry I can't help.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. By the way , thank you anyway for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was with the scope `openid`.

After removing the openid from scope ( which I dont need it), `userService` is working as expected

```
userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpointConfig -> userInfoEndpointConfig.userService(customOauth2UserService))
```

configuration

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=profile,email
```