# Spring Boot Resource Server & Keycloak scope vs. role

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect, spring-oauth2

is there anybody out there who is using Spring Boot Resource Server & Keycloak?

I configured my application.properties with
`spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri = http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/<myrealm>`

In my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter i can use the client scopes like
`.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_read")`

but i'm not able to use the roles!
`.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")`

The information is availabe in the jwt, but spring does somehow not use it. Do anybody know where i can find a peace of documentation that describes the mapping?
Somehow i think there is a node in my head, but where and which one ?

Thats my jwt:

```
  "exp": 1603373908,
  "iat": 1603373608,
  "jti": "0b18b386-9f62-4c42-810e-692ccc4ed7d1",
  "iss": "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "4c973896-5761-41fc-8217-07c5d13a004b",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "web_app",
  "session_state": "17411db5-8d50-4f25-b520-9a3e8b19fd67",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "*"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "test",
      "ROLE_USER",
      "offline_access",
      "ROLE_ADMIN",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "email profile",
  "email_verified": true,
  "roles": [
    "test",
    "ROLE_USER",
    "offline_access",
    "ROLE_ADMIN",
    "uma_authorization"
  ],
  "name": "Admin Administrator",
  "preferred_username": "admin",
  "given_name": "Admin",
  "family_name": "Administrator",
  "email": "admin@localhost"
}
```

Thanks a lot
Fredy

Answer (score 6):

You need to define a `Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>>` that extracts the roles from Keycloak's `realm_access` (null checks omitted for brevity):

```
public class KeycloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt source) {
        Map<String, Object> realmAccess = source.getClaimAsMap("realm_access");
        List<String> roles = (List<String>) realmAccess.get("roles");
        return roles.stream()
                .map(rn -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + rn))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Please note that this only extracts the Roles. If you need Scopes *and* Roles, check Spring's default `JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` for an code example.

Define it in a `JwtAuthenticationConverter`:

```
private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new KeycloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter());
    return jwtConverter;
}
```

And finally use that in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            // [...]
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the way Spring Security is parsing/extracting roles details from the JWT token. For example, in MicroProfile specification, it's mentioned that roles list will be extracted from "groups" property of the token.

Check [RoleVoter](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html) documentation in Spring Security. Seems it expects role names to specifically start with the *ROLE_* prefix. Maybe that's the case for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the versions used but I had the same problem with [spring-security-oauth2-resource-server 5.2.2.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-resource-server/5.2.2.RELEASE).
This method:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter#getAuthorities
```

is responsible by default to get the authorities from the jwt. It only checks for the claim names `scope` and `scp`. However, as this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234971) suggests, you can provide a `CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter` and extract the roles as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your security configuration define jwt authentication converter. You can set your claim name to be used by granted authorities converter.

Something like below, should work:

```java
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;


@Bean
public JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter() {
    // You can use setAuthoritiesClaimName method
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
    return jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;

    // You can also add your custom converter here
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    final JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter());
    
    http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt()
        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
}
```