# Springboot 2.7 with oidc bearer token always redirects to login page

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I have a client Springboot app which needs to access an oidc-protected REST service, so no UI component or UI login. I have the following yaml in the client:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-service:
            client-id: client-id
            client-secret: client-secret
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
        provider:
          my-service:
            token-uri: https://mytokenhost.mydomain/token
```

which points to a Keycloak server on which I have configured an oidc client with a service account and enabled it. I use a WebClient to connect to the REST service which is configured like:

```
  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(final OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    final ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
        new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("my-service");

    return WebClient.builder()
        .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
        .build();
  }
```

I also needed to manually define an OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager for the WebClient to work:

```
  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
      final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
      final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

    final OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().refreshToken().clientCredentials().build();

    final AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
        new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);

    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
  }
```

And then use the WebClient to make a call to the REST service:

```
    final String s =  webClient
        .method(HttpMethod.GET)
        .uri("http://localhost:8080/my-rest-service/service?param1=value")
        .attributes(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId(
            "catalogue-services"))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
```

Via IntelliJ I can see I get a token back, however no matter what I do Springboot redirects to the login page of the REST service. The REST service has yaml:

```
spring:
 security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-service:
            client-id: client-id
            client-secret: my-secret
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
        provider:
          my-service:
            token-uri: https://mytokenhost.mydomain/token/openid-connect/token
```

and a security configuration in the REST service:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests(
            a ->
                a.antMatchers("/", "/error", "/someUrl")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
        .oauth2Login();
    return http.build();
  }
```

What is happening is that after successfully authenticating against KeyCloak, the REST service security filter is flagging the authentication as an anonymous login, presumably because the role is ROLE_ANONYMOUS and/or principal is anonymousUser. I can see the service account user name come back, the roles are included as well but maybe not being picked up. I have a realm role which is exposed in the token realm_access.roles and a client role which is exposed in resource_access.my-service.roles. When I debug the decision voting in the AffirmativeBase class I get:

```
AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, 
Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true,
 Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null],
 Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
```

I haven't used the Keycloak adapter since they look to be deprecated and the documentation still uses the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which is also deprecated in the Spring Security model.

It's likely I'm missing something really simple, but if anyone has done machine-to-machine oidc with Springboot and Keycloak and knows any tricks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "REST service" you mean a spring `@RestControtroller` (or `@Controller` with `@ResponseBody`), then it is an OAuth2 **resource-server**, not a client (like you configured in your "REST service" yaml file).

You can have a look at [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) which provide with OAuth2 concepts you need and sample configurations for resource-servers.

Comment: Yes, reconfiguring as a resource server solved the problem (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-resource-server), thank you. And I did find some info on pulling out roles as well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69331013/springboot-oauth2-with-keycloak-not-returning-mapped-roles-as-authorities)

Comment: There are few limitations to the Baeldung tutorials you point: it is pre 2.7 and the test they set-up are integration testing (with restassured). "Mine" are made with latest boot versions (no usage of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter) and show unit-testing (with MockMvc or WebTestClient and more importantly without any authorization-server)

Comment: plus, extracting roles can be as easy as defining a property in your yaml file if you use `spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server` as you can see there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication (`com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.client-id.roles`, replacing `client-id` if you use Keycloak client-roles mapper)

Comment: Yeah, I only used Baeldung as a guide, much of the info on forums is out of date when it comes to Springboot security. It turns out I could get away with using Keycloak client scope rather than roles, which Springboot places into GrantedAuthority objects. But yes your libraries are useful for the roles, shame Springboot doesn't allow the same in its autoconfigure. Cheers.